# mysql server 2008 monitor the output of workers over time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem to ask:

```
Time     Pass    Fail
-------------------------
08:30    10       2
09:30    12       1
10:30    20       0
11:30    30       40
```

I need Result:

```
   08:30       09:30       10:30       11:30
 Pass Fail   Pass Fail    Pass Fail   Pass Fail
  10   2      12   1       20   0      30   40
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: You want to have columns in columns? Like, In column `8:30` you want two columns: `Pass` and `Fail`? If so, you better switch to Excel. What you can do, is to create two separate columns, e.g.: `8:30 Pass` and `8:30 Fail`.

Comment: You can't get two title columns in a SELECT statement. What is the format of the SELECT statement (result from the database) you need, to produce the output?

Comment: if code C# could not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest you can get:

```
declare @x table(
  [Time] time,
  [Pass] smallint,
  [Fail] smallint
)

insert into @x values ('08:30', 10, 2),('09:30', 12, 1),('10:30', 20, 0),('11:30', 30, 40)

select case when [Time] = '08:30' then Pass end As [Pass 08:30],
   case when [Time] = '08:30' then Fail end As [Fail 08:30],
   case when [Time] = '09:30' then Pass end As [Pass 09:30],
   case when [Time] = '09:30' then Fail end As [Fail 09:30],
   case when [Time] = '10:30' then Pass end As [Pass 10:30],
   case when [Time] = '10:30' then Fail end As [Fail 10:30],
   case when [Time] = '11:30' then Pass end As [Fail 11:30],
   case when [Time] = '11:30' then Fail end As [Fail 11:30]
from @x
```

Comment: oke it's return resuilt: <br>

Pass 08:30      Fail 08:30
    10                      2

Comment: I want to include 2 columns ''Pass and Fail" in a column "Time"

Comment: It's impossible in SQL Server, please read my comment below your question.

Comment: If use in C #, maybe not? Thank

Comment: Well, in C# you can do various things... But then you need to customize elements on your form. You can't do that directly in SQL.

Comment: Can you give an example? Thank you very much

Comment: Sory, but I won't write working software for you... You should hire freelancer :)

Comment: :)) oke. Thank you so much! Wish you a good day.